# How do you find an 'M' by 'M' submatrix in the center of an input 'N' by 'N' matrix? (In Matlab)

Tags: matlab

How do I write a function in Matlab to output the M x M submatrix at the center of an N x N input matrix?  The function should have two input arguments—the N x N input matrix (2D array) and the size of the square submatrix, M, to be extracted from the input matrix.  The sole output should be the M x M submatrix at the center of the input matrix.  The function should use for loops to extract the submatrix and not use colon notation or any built-in functions for this part of the code.  The function should work for any square input matrix where N ≥ 3.  If N is even, M should be even.  If N is odd, M should be odd.

[Here is a picture of my flowchart so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABiPZ.png)

Comment: Please show your attempt and ask something specific about your code if needed. Also, do you really need to use loops? It's much easier to do it without loops

Comment: Yes, part of my assignment was to use for loops and I honestly don't know where to start. I have started by creating a flowchart. I will attach it in a minute.

Comment: I'm sorry that you don't know how to approach it, but questions here should be more specific. I suggest you use a loop for the rows, then a loop for the columns, and in the inner body loop you read a value from the input and write it into an entry in the output

Comment: Thank you @LuisMendo

Comment: Some useful functions to solve this task may include `size()` and `rand()` for generating random test matrices.

Answer (score 1):

### Using For-Loops and Offsetting Indexing

### Preface:

Here I like to visualize this question as trimming the matrix. The amount to trim I denote in this example is `Trim_Amount`. The `Trim_Amount` dictates the size of the sub-matrix and the start point to begin reading/saving the sub-matrix.

[image: Scanning/Saving Sub-Matrix]

Since the trim amount is always taken from each side you can expect the sub-matrix to have dimensions in the form:

**Sub-Matrix Width = M - (2 × Trim_Amount)**

2 × Trim_Amount will always result in an even number therefore the following can be said:

if M is even → M - (Even Number) → Even Number 
if M is odd → M - (Even Number) → Odd Number

---

### Test Output Results:

[image: Output Results]
I recommend going through the code to filter through any unexpected issues.

### Full Script:

```
Dimension = 7;
Matrix = round(100*rand(Dimension));
Trim_Amount = 1;

[Sub_Matrix] = Grab_Sub_Matrix(Matrix,Trim_Amount);
Matrix
Sub_Matrix
    
%Function definition%
function [Sub_Matrix] = Grab_Sub_Matrix(Matrix,Trim_Amount) 

%Minimum of M must be 5 since N >= 3%
[M,~] = size(Matrix);


%Ensuring the trimming factor does not go over possible range%
Max_Trimming_Factor = M - 3;
if(Trim_Amount > Max_Trimming_Factor)
Trim_Amount = Max_Trimming_Factor;
end


%Fill in the boundaries%
Row_Start_Limit = Trim_Amount + 1;
Column_Start_Limit = Trim_Amount + 1;

%Creating sub-matrix based on amount of trimming%
Sub_Matrix = zeros(M-(2*Trim_Amount),M-(2*Trim_Amount));

for Row = 1: length(Sub_Matrix)
   for Column = 1: length(Sub_Matrix) 
    
%    fprintf("(%d,%d)\n",Row,Column);  
   Sub_Matrix(Row,Column) = Matrix(Row + Row_Start_Limit-1,Column + Column_Start_Limit-1);
    
   end
end

end
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**